# Dimple JS multiple y axis - change default sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, dimple.js

When I have 2 axes, my data is sorted on the 2d series ('Group' column).

I would like either to keep the original sorting of the data or to sort on the 1st series ('Value' column).

Here is the code for the chart

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var data = [
 { 'Label': 'aaaa', 'Value': '135.54943277777', 'Group': '18.3948393336644'}, 
 { 'Label': 'bbb', 'Value': '120.80073333333', 'Group': '10.4281640646934'}, 
 { 'Label': 'ccc', 'Value': '110.54883277777', 'Group': '9.66131377875796'}, 
 { 'Label': 'ddd', 'Value': '98.86206666666', 'Group': '9.91368107242412'}, 
 { 'Label': 'eee', 'Value': '97.57636666666', 'Group': '9.49774852202884'}, 
 { 'Label': 'fff', 'Value': '96.04330000000', 'Group': '11.3224795444171'}, 
 { 'Label': 'ggg', 'Value': '73.57493333333', 'Group': '18.7054825008656'}, 
 { 'Label': 'hhh', 'Value': '66.72536666666', 'Group': '7.91852934981023'}, 
 { 'Label': 'iii', 'Value': '65.80693333333', 'Group': '10.2305178662186'}
];

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setMargins("60px", "60px", "40px", "40px");
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Label");
var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
var y2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Group");
myChart.addSeries("Value", dimple.plot.bar, [x, y1]);
myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line, [x, y2]);
myChart.draw();
```

And the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xgmtuqq5/

How can that be achieved?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add just OrderRule in your Code for Original Sorting or by using the "Value" column such as:

```
x.addOrderRule("Label"); //for original sorting
```

and

```
x.addOrderRule("Value"); //for sorting using the column "Value"
```

You can also sort in Descending order by setting true in the coding such as:

```
x.addOrderRule("Value",true); // for sorting in descending order
```